# Using Furnace and Package A/C Transformers

Tags: hvac

I just got a new Honeywell TH8321 Stat. The old stat jut used the R jumper for the Rc and had the G/Y tied as one. I would like to use both xmr's and hook the yellow and green to their position on the stat. The furnace has no green terminal. The stat has R/h and R/c but one common screw. Both the The package a/c and the furnace has a blue. The stat uses the furnace blue to operate. I know the Rh and R/c are separated. Can the commons from both be tied together ? It there any problems that might arise from using two xmr's ? Thanks and God bless.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot tie the commons together (we'll you can, but it's not that simply and beyond the scope of this answer).

Check with the manufacturer of the thermostat, to determine which common you should use.  I think the common associated with `Rc` is typically used, but it could be different with your thermostat.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with Thermostat 101. All a T'stat is a group of switches that turn certain things on and off in sequences to condition the air in your dwelling. The transformer is the power source (we're going to call it 24V) and it feeds from a unit to the T'stat. The T'stat will generally has corresponding connection points that supply power back to the units. These designations are:

Rc - power for cooling

Rh - power for heating

C - common

G - fan

Y - cooling

W - heat

O - reversing valve (heat pump)

Keep in mind these are only designations not color coding and even though most installers try and keep it color coded it does not mean that it is always that way. For instance suppose you get a 5 wire T'stat cable and the colors are white, brown, red, blue, and green. What is important is that the same wire is connecting W in the T'stat to W at the heater location, etc.

If you are using just one transformer (xfmr) then you need to jumper Rc to Rh and the common to the C terminal in the T'stat. If you want to use both transformers then you need to connect the xfmr from the package ac to Rc and the other xfmr form the heater is connected to Rh and both commons are attached to the C terminal in the T'stat. **Polarity of the xfmr's is very important**. Make sure you check the polarities at each xfmr. you should have 24V to ground and 0V to ground on each xfmr and the common must be the 0V to ground.